# Trouble including JSON in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I've got an angular controller containing a json object

```
app.controller("buildControl", function($scope){

$scope.buildData = [
{
    'title':'Workspace',
    'options': [{
        'title': 'Studio'
    },{
        'title': 'Garage'
    },{
        'title': 'Blank'
    }]
},{
    'title':'Frame',
    'options': [{
        'title': 'Studio'
    },{
        'title': 'Garage'
    },{
        'title': 'Blank'
    }]
}]
});
```

I'm using this data to iterate the object's arrays using ng-repeat (plus I have other functions in my controller that use the data).

Everything runs fine until I moved the json out into it's own file and used $http to include it.

```
app.controller("buildControl",function($http, $scope){

$http.get("json/buildData.js")
  .success(function(response){
    $scope.buildData = response.data;
  }).error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

The only errors I get in my console are from all my other functions breaking without the data they need to run, plus an 'undefined' from my console log. So I know that it's going to '.error'.

I figured maybe I had the filepath wrong, have tried changing prefixing it with '../' to go up a directory out of my controllers. No luck. If I put the json in the same folder and just write;

```
.get("buildData.js")
```

I get this as the error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /buildData.js was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

But then I sort out the filepath and it goes back to undefined. So I don't think this is the problem.

(I'm doing this using MAMP and having no HTTP errors associated with trying to get files locally).

Any help?

Comment: Before the line `  $scope.buildData = response.data;` add `alert(typeof response.data)` and see if it is a `string` or `object`.  If it is a string, then it's raw JSON that must be parsed first.

Comment: Why make it a .js file? Why not make it a true .json file?

Comment: I have also changed the file extension to and from .json, no dice.

Comment: Jeremy, adding this here does not work because the .success function isn't running so no data is being sent over and the alert isn't being run

Comment: Path is clearly wrong if you get 404 status returned from server

Comment: @charlietfl the 404 error only came up when I changed the path from what I was initially doing (I was doing that to show I'd checked the path was previously correct)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need to use $http here, why not include your data from a service, something like:

```
  angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .service('buildData', buildData);

  function buildData() {
    return [{
      'title':'Workspace',
      'options': [{
         'title': 'Studio'
      },{
        'title': 'Garage'
      },{
        'title': 'Blank'
      }]
    ...
    }]
  };
```

Your controller would look something like this:

```
.controller('buildControl', buildControl);

  buildControl.$inject = ['$scope', 'buildData'];
  function buildControl($scope, buildData) {
    $scope.buildData = buildData;
    ...
  }
```